# GCD not respecting dispatch time intervals

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch, timing

i am having difficulty getting GCD to fire my dispatch at the correct time. It seems to miss by huge margins and i don't understand why it's happening.

i send 3 dispatches to my queue for execution . .one at 5 mins in the future ( 300 seconds ) one at 10 minutes ( 600 secpnds )  and another at 20 minutes (1200 seconds)
All three fire and the audio file plays in all three dispatches but not at their designated times.

The first one fires after 10 minutes
The second one after 16 minutes 
and the last one fires at 21 minutes..

These fire times vary a bit in testing but they NEVER fire when they are supposed to..

If you know why it would be greatly appreciated . .also 
i've tried this with my iphone and ipad ( same result ) ..

At the top in my viewcontroller i have this code bit ..

```
 var myAudio = AVAudioPlayer()
 var timer: DispatchSourceTimer!
```

Then after clicking a button i send 3 dispatches like this below one but with different times in each .. then lock the device which RESIGNS the app. and wait for the short 16 second audio file to play. 
i also have the key Application_does_not_run_in_background set to true in my plist.info file so my app does not go to the background when the user locks the screen.

First Create my queue:

```
let Myqueue = DispatchQueue(label: "Myqueue")
```

Then here is the dispatch to my Myqueue - same thing 3 times with different intervals etc. .

```
Myqueue.asyncAfter (wallDeadline:DispatchWallTime.now() + 900.0, qos: .userInitiated, flags: DispatchWorkItemFlags(rawValue: 0)) {
        print(Date())
        self.myAudio.prepareToPlay()
        self.myAudio.play()
        }
```

i am running Xcode 9 .. and compiling for ios 8 and up 
i spent many hours testing trying to figure out why this doesn't work. 
Found many answers here in the past - hope someone can help 
Cheers

Comment: Of course, we suppose that you meant 300 seconds for 5 minutes, not 600?

Comment: You had better review your question.

Comment: Thanks - edited to show the seconds for all 3 intervals ..

Comment: Try using `userInteractive` or changing the priority of your queue to something high.. Also.. AVAudioPlayer.play is already asynchronous..

Comment: Thanks Brandon .. i had already tried UserInteractive with no differential noticed .. Actually as i understand the queues ..  because of asyncAfter my item is popped off of my own serial queue and then automatically scheduled onto the mainQueue asynchronously which already runs in highest priority .. i tried way too many things  to post them all here . but nothing seems to make the queue run at the designated time .. i have noticed that when my device is charging - the times seem to be closest to the run times .. but i have no idea why that might be so .. frustrating problem .. a bug maybe ?